# Error at or near delete in supabase database functions

Tags: postgresql, supabase

edit: i found no solution and i used a netlify function

I have a scheduled database functions using pg_cron in supabase all it does is delete rows from a News table more than a week old but it returns this error: `Failed to create function: failed to update pg.functions with the given ID: syntax error at or near "delete"`
Here my functions

```
BEGIN
select cron.schedule (
      'saturday-cleanup', -- name of the cron job
          '30 3 * * 6', -- Saturday at 3:30am (GMT)
              $$ delete from News where event_time < now() - interval '1 week' $$
              );
END
```

The function is in public scheme btw

Comment: Did you try to add a semi-colon at the end of your statement and see if it works? Try running the query in the SQL editor, does it also error out?

Comment: I tried and it didn't work so i removed every dollar sign and now it says this `Failed to create function: failed to update pg.functions with the given ID: syntax error at or near "FROM"`

Comment: What's the `BEGIN` and `END` statements for? Have you tried following https://supabase.com/docs/guides/database/extensions/pgcron#delete-data-every-week ?